# What are the differentiation between \l vs \d in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, pgadmin-4

[image] And I want to know the details about template0 and template1 database

Comment: Read the docs here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) under the section *Meta-Commands*. Or in `psql` do `\?` to get brief descriptions of commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
\l
```

Lists the databases. You can also run `\list` with similar results. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

```
\d
```

stands for **describe** and shows the list of tables and other relations in the database.

Basically you need to switch to the database of your interest first, via running

```
\c template0
```

or

```
\c template1
```

depending where you want to connect and then run

```
\d
```

to list the tables in the current database. Since you do not specify a pattern in the above, it will display everything.

[image]

Now, if you are interested to see table structures, run `\d tablename`

Running

```
\dt+ *.*
```

will display all tables.

Comment: You should not be using a  link to 10 years past EOL version of Postgres(8.3). A lot has changed in that time.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver edited my answer with a newer link

Comment: That went EOL in November 2022. Go here [Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html) to see what is supported. Hint you want `Current`.